# How to get the original type (instead of E) for a Parameterized type with generics using reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8

I have a question about Java reflection and generic types.

If I do these instructions:

```
private static void test() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    inspect(list.getClass());
}

private static void inspect(Class<?> clazz){
    System.out.println(clazz.getGenericSuperclass());

    Type genericSuperclass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)genericSuperclass;
    Type rawType = pt.getRawType();
    Type type = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println(rawType + " "+type);

    List<TypeVariable> tps = new ArrayList<TypeVariable>(Arrays.asList(clazz.getTypeParameters()));
    tps.forEach(tp -> {
        Type[] bounds = tp.getBounds();     
        System.out.println(bounds[0] + " " + tp.getTypeName());
    });

}
```

the output is:

```
java.util.AbstractList<E>
class java.util.AbstractList E
class java.lang.Object E
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to **obtain the original String.class** type instead of a **generic E** element.

It is possible?

Thanks.

EDIT

I have noticed that the real type can be obtained in this way:

```
Class<?> typeNameClass = Class.forName(clazz.getTypeName());
if (typeNameClass.equals(ArrayList.class)){
    ArrayList<?> objlist = (ArrayList<?>)object;
    objlist.forEach(obj -> {                    
        System.out.println("obj="+obj + " "+obj.getClass());
    });
}
```

In this way, supposing that the list is {"a", "b", "c"}, it prints:

```
obj=a class java.lang.String
obj=b class java.lang.String
obj=c class java.lang.String
```

It's not necessary to know the type of an ArrayList, because iterating in it we can retrieve the real type of the object in the list.

Comment: Directly, no, there is no way. The caller needs to provide more information.

Comment: Please clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: It's a simple test; My idea is to pass a certain class to a method, and that method must to investigate the input class to do some operations.

Comment: You can't do that like this. There are some tricks and black magic to make it work, see the linked question.

Comment: Generics is assuming that you don't need to know what type it is. Why do you want to know what type it is? You could try and access the element inside the list, and then pass that in to determine what kind of elements it can hold. That is all I can think of though.